# Как создать кастомный балун на точки мультимаршрута?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

Всем привет.

Есть мультимаршрут с нефиксированным количеством точек. Типа такого: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving

Необходимо на каждую точку накинуть балун или хинт, и прокидывать туда инфу по этой точки. Я не нашел никаких примеров или методов, связанных с этим. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Точки, сколько бы их не нужно было добавить в маршрут, всё равно имеют координаты. Самый простой способ решить вашу задачу - перед добавлением точек в маршрут геокодировать их, а после после построения маршрута добавлять эти точки на карту с нужным содержимым балуна/хинта [стандартными методами](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark) API Яндекс.Карт.